# Finding Injectivity in function

Tags: functions, inverse-function

I have a doubt with the following problem. I have to find if the function is injective, surjective and if bijective find the inverse function

$$f : \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathbb{N},\qquad
f(a) = 
     \begin{cases}
       2a  & \text{if } a >0, \\
       1 - 2a & \text{if } a \le 0. \\
     \end{cases}$$

The solution to the problem:

Injectivity: $f(a)=f(b) \Rightarrow a=b$. Taking a $x_{1}$,$x_{2} \in \mathbb{Z}$, I separate into the following cases:

1) $x_ {1} > 0$, $x_{2} > 0:\; 2x_{1} = 2x_{2} \Rightarrow x_{1} = x_{2}$

2) $x_ {1} \le 0$, $x_{2} \le 0:\; 1-2x_{1} = 1-2x_{2} \Rightarrow x_{1} = x_{2}$

3) $x_{1} > 0, x_{2} \le 0:\;2x_{1} = 1-2x_{2} \Rightarrow 2x_{1} + 2x_{2} = 1 \Rightarrow (x_{1} + x_{2}) = 1/2$

The case $x_{2} > 0$, $x_{1} \le 0$, gives the same answer as the third case. My question is that if this conclusion makes the function not injective, or it simply is telling me that this is a case that cannot happen since $x_{1}$,$x_{2} \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Putting aside this, the function also is surjective and I could find the inverse function, that is

$$f^{-1} : \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z},\qquad f^{-1}(a) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \text{a/2} &\text{if $a$ is even,} \\
       \text{(1 - a)/2} &\text{if $a$ is odd.} \\
     \end{cases}
$$

Is this correct?

PD: First time writing LATEX, feedback is very welcomed!

Comment: Everything is correct. Very good. (Due to symmetry, you don't have to go through the fourth case)

Comment: For the third case, you suppose that $f(a)=f(b)$ with $a>0$ and $b\leq 0$.  But... $f(a)$ would be an even number while $f(b)$ would be an odd number, making it impossible.  Thus the correct conclusion there is that $f(a)$ cannot have equalled $f(b)$ in the first place if $a$ and $b$ were of different signs and so it can be ignored.

Comment: Is $0$ an element of $\mathbb N$ according to your definition of $\mathbb N$?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! My definition of Natural numbers doesn't include the 0 element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 3rd and 4th cases,  you just have to say it can't happen since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are integers.

However, I would put all this differently:  the *restrictions* of $f$ to positive integers and to nonpositive integers are, separately, injective (affine functions).

Furthermore, if one of $x_1,x_ 2$ is $>0$ and the other $\le0$, one of $f(x_1), f(x_2)$ is an even and the other an odd integer. So they can't be equal, which proves that, *globally*, $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 0):

The function is injective if you draw the graph. It looks like a ''V''.

But it is not surjective, since $0$ doesn't lie in the image: If $a>0$, then $f(a)=2a>0$ and if $a$ is non-positive, the function has the form: $f(0) = 1$, $f(-1)=3$, $f(-2)=5$ and so on.

Comment: I understand. I should have clarified that my codomain is without the 0 element. In that case it starts at 1.